# TypeError: write() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'

Tags: python, odoo

I'm using new API, I want to change the state after clicking the button of my wizard but it returns an error every time I click the button:

```
TypeError: write() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/api.py", line 399, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/custom_addons/my_module/models/test_module.py", line 14, in action_credit
    sale_order.write(sale_id,{'state': 'order_confirm'})
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/api.py", line 266, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/workspace/odoo8/openerp/api.py", line 592, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, self.ids, *args, **old_kwargs)
TypeError: write() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'
```

.py file:

```
from openerp.osv import orm
from openerp import models, api, _ 

class TestOverride(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'test.override'

    @api.multi
    def action_override(self):
        sale_order = self.env['sale.order']
        sale_id = self._context['sale_id']
        sale_order.write(sale_id,{'state': 'order_confirm'})
        return True

class sale_order(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

    @api.multi
    def action_button_confirm(self):
        for order_id in self:
            #
                if condition:
                    return {
                        'name': 'Test',
                        'view_mode': 'form',
                        'view_type': 'form',
                        'res_model': 'test.override',
                        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                        'nodestroy': True,
                        'target': 'new',
                        'context': {'sale_id': order_id.id}
                            }

        self.write(order_id, {'state': 'order_confirm'})
        return True
```

Comment: This may just be an error here on Stack Overflow, but you've got a stray, unmatched single-quote on the first line of the `return` statement in `sale_order.action_button_confirm`. I doubt that's related to your reported issue (you would get a `SyntaxError` for a mismatched quote like that).

Comment: I just forgot to put the quote but same error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass **order_id** while calling write method. Just pass the values to it.

```
self.write({'state': 'order_confirm'})
```